# Can an executable circumvent the firewall?

Tags: windows, security, firewall, process

On Windows suppose I went into my firewall settings and simply block an *exe* file; if I then call this *exe* file of course it will be unable to connect to the internet, but what if this *exe*, in its running, calls other executables? Will those other executables be able to connect to the internet despite the initial blockage of the initial *exe* file?

And if indeed the answer is yes, how can I prevent an *exe* file from not only connecting to the internet but also prevent it from calling other processes/programs that will connect to the net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if a firewall blocked executable calls another, then the called program will be able to connect the internet.

Suppose you have blocked a.exe. But a.exe does not connect the internet, the connection is done by b.exe. a.exe uses b.exe to connect the internet. And if you don't block b.exe, then a.exe will be able to connect the internet. You have to block both exe files.

Here the solution is you have to install a tool named Process explorer. Unblock firewall for the initial executable. Launch Process explorer and expand that initial exe file. See what resources are used by it. Then block initial exe file and other resources to communicate firewall

Comment: The more robust solution is to block the traffic at the network level or prevent the execution of the executable entirely with a group policy.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. Also I am thinking about using Glasswire. It will say the first network activity of applications. So you can easily block them

Comment: Just block everything and then create exceptions to the blocking rule only for processes/ports you want.